# $K_{2,2}$ with the same color for every coloring of $K_{3,7}$

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, bipartite-graphs

How can I prove that for every way of coloring the edges of the bipartite graph $K_{3,7}$ with two colors (red, blue) there is a $K_{2,2}$ graph with the same color?

Comment: If the graph is $A_1,A_2,A_3$, $B_1,B_2,...,B_7$, where $A,B$ coincides with  the bipartition, what happens if $A_1,A_2,B_1$  are red and the rest are blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the monochromatic "V" shapes in the graph: pairs of edges like

[image: V shape]

which have the same color and meet in the part of size $7$.

*(At @bof's advice, I've flipped the picture for an argument that works better.)*

From each vertex in the bottom vertex, there are three edges up, and at least two of them share a color, forming one of these "V" shapes.

There are $7$ bottom vertices, and three possible "V" shapes, so one "V" shape occurs three times:

[image: three Vs]

If it occurs three times, two of those share a color, and once you pick those two "V" shapes, you've found a monochromatic $K_{2,2}$.

---

By the way, a different way to think about the problem is to say that we are coloring a $3 \times 7$ grid and want to find a rectangle whose vertices are all given the same color:

[image: rectangle coloring]

Here, if we take the cell in position $(x,y)$ to correspond to the edge between the $x^{\text{th}}$ vertex in one part and the $y^{\text{th}}$ vertex in the other part, a rectangle precisely corresponds to a $K_{2,2}$.

We can prove the rectangle claim just like the argument above, by looking at how columns in this grid are colored.

Comment: $\binom 72=21$, how do you get the pigeonhole principle giving 3 common V's there?

Comment: Maybe a tad easier: For each top vertex, choose a monochromatic "$\Lambda$" shape. Two of the seven top vertices have the same color and same bottom vertices in their monochromatic $\Lambda.$ (By the way, I'm sure you guessed right, that the question is about ***edge*** colorings, but I wish people would get the OP to state the question properly before they go ahead and answer it.)

Comment: @bof Thank you: your argument is much better, so I've rephrased the answer to use it. (I've flipped the graph, though, to keep using the letter V rather than $\Lambda$.)

Comment: thank you for this wonderfull answer!...sorry if i wasn't clear with describing my question this is how i got it...